# PFQuery and PFRelation Crash app when Run

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, pfrelation

Hello everyone I would like to ask a help to those who can ' give it to me ... Before you start to use specific Parse.com as manager for the data in my App
In my FILE.h I created a PFObject called PostDetails

PostDetail in my file.m is used in the TableView to display a list of posts .

The user of my app can ' create a report with a post by PFRelation

Now to retrieve all the relations which the current user has with certain post I created this query

```
- (void)  LoadDataGoPointAssigned {
    FFCustomCellWithImage CCIButtonAddGoPoint * = [ [ FFCustomCellWithImage alloc] init ] ;
    
    self.RelationForGoPointAssignToPost = [ [ PFUser currentUser ] objectForKey : @ " PostGoPoint "];
    
    PFQuery QueryForPostGoPoint * = [ self.RelationForGoPointAssignToPost query ] ;
    [ QueryForPostGoPoint whereKey : @ " objectId " equalTo : self.PostDetails.objectId ] ;
    [ QueryForPostGoPoint findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * objects, NSError * error ) {
        if ( error) {
            
        Else { }
        
        if ( [ objects count] > 0) {
            CCIButtonAddGoPoint.AddGoPoint.selected = YES ;
            UIImage * ButtonDisable = [ UIImage imageNamed : @ " FFIMG_Medal_Blu "];
            [ CCIButtonAddGoPoint.AddGoPoint setImage : ButtonDisable forState : UIControlStateNormal ] ;
        }}
    } ] ;

}
```

My problem is that when I make the run the application crashes and gives me the breakpoint this line ... Where am I doing wrong ?

```
[QueryForPostGoPoint whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.PostDetails.objectId];
```

I apologize for how I expressed myself but I'm using a translator are not native English speakers ...
I hope it's all understandable ... Sorry again ...

Comment: Did you find why it was crashing. as I am also crashing on [PFQuery whereKey] line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line you can see there are extra spaces around the name of the class `PostGoPoint`.

```
self.RelationForGoPointAssignToPost = [ [ PFUser currentUser ] objectForKey : @ " PostGoPoint "];
```

Perhaps it fails when the class name is access in the whereKey is used.